# how to get ticking timer with dynamic label?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

What im trying to do is that whenever cursor is on label it must show the time elapsed since when it is created it does well by subtracting (def on_enter(i)) the value but i want it to be ticking while cursor is still on label.

I tried using after function as newbie i do not understand it well to use on dynamic labels.

any help will be appreciated thx

code:

```
from Tkinter import *

import datetime
date  = datetime.datetime
now = date.now()

master=Tk()

list_label=[]
k=[]

time_var=[]
result=[]
names=[]

def delete(i):
    k[i]=max(k)+1
    time_var[i]='<deleted>'
    list_label[i].pack_forget()

def create():#new func
    i=k.index(max(k))

    for j in range(i+1,len(k)):
        if k[j]==0:
            list_label[j].pack_forget()

    list_label[i].pack(anchor='w')

    time_var[i]=time_now()

    for j in range(i+1,len(k)):
        if k[j]==0:
            list_label[j].pack(anchor='w')

    k[i]=0
###########################
def on_enter(i):
    list_label[i].configure(text=time_now()-time_var[i])

def on_leave(i):
    list_label[i].configure(text=names[i])

def time_now():
    now = date.now()
    return date(now.year,now.month,now.day,now.hour,now.minute,now.second)
############################

for i in range(11):
    lb=Label(text=str(i),anchor=W)
    list_label.append(lb)
    lb.pack(anchor='w')
    lb.bind("<Button-3>",lambda event,i=i:delete(i))
    k.append(0)
    names.append(str(i))

    lb.bind("<Enter>",lambda event,i=i: on_enter(i))
    lb.bind("<Leave>",lambda event,i=i: on_leave(i))
    time_var.append(time_now())

master.bind("<Control-Key-z>",lambda event: create())
mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use `after` like this:

```
###########################
def on_enter(i):
    list_label[i].configure(text=time_now()-time_var[i])
    list_label[i].timer = list_label[i].after(1000, on_enter, i)

def on_leave(i):
    list_label[i].configure(text=names[i])
    list_label[i].after_cancel(list_label[i].timer)
```

---

However, your approach here is all wrong. You currently have some functions and a list of data. What you should do is make a single object that contains the functions and data together and make a list of those. That way you can write your code for a single Label and just duplicate that. It makes your code a lot simpler partly because you no longer need to keep track of "i". Like this:

```
import Tkinter as tk
from datetime import datetime

def time_now():
    now = datetime.now()
    return datetime(now.year,now.month,now.day,now.hour,now.minute,now.second)

class Kiran(tk.Label):
    """A new type of Label that shows the time since creation when the mouse hovers"""
    hidden = []
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        tk.Label.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        self.name = self['text']
        self.time_var = time_now()
        self.bind("<Enter>", self.on_enter)
        self.bind("<Leave>", self.on_leave)
        self.bind("<Button-3>", self.hide)

    def on_enter(self, event=None):
        self.configure(text=time_now()-self.time_var)
        self.timer = self.after(1000, self.on_enter)

    def on_leave(self, event=None):
        self.after_cancel(self.timer) # cancel the timer
        self.configure(text=self.name)

    def hide(self, event=None):
        self.pack_forget()
        self.hidden.append(self) # add this instance to the list of hidden instances

    def show(self):
        self.time_var = time_now() # reset time
        self.pack(anchor='w')

def undo(event=None):
    '''if there's any hidden Labels, show one'''
    if Kiran.hidden:
        Kiran.hidden.pop().show()

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('200x200')
    for i in range(11):
        lb=Kiran(text=i)
        lb.pack(anchor='w')
    root.bind("<Control-Key-z>",undo)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

More notes:

- Don't use `lambda` unless you are forced to; it's known to cause bugs.
- Don't use wildcard imports (`from module import *`), they cause bugs and are against PEP8.
- Put everything in functions.
- Use long, descriptive names. Single letter names just waste time. Think of names as tiny comments.
- Add a lot more comments to your code so that other people don't have to guess what the code is supposed to do.
- Try a more beginner oriented forum for questions like this, like learnpython.reddit.com

Comment: Thank you so much i will remember it..you were so helpful :)